# Swagger Spring Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Tags: spring, heroku, swagger

I have a Spring Swagger application and I can successfully run on localhost. But when I run the same project on Heroku I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://force-com-rest-swagger.herokuapp.com/api/doc/api/v1/account. Origin https://force-com-rest-swagger.herokuapp.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Below is my swagger js config:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        displaySwaggerDocuments();

        function displaySwaggerDocuments() {
            var url = '<c:url value="/api/resourceList"/>';
            window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
                discoveryUrl: url,
                dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
                supportHeaderParams: false,
                supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'],
                apiKey: "",
                onComplete: function (swaggerApi, swaggerUi) {
                    if (console) {
                        console.log("Loaded SwaggerUI")
                        console.log(swaggerApi);
                        console.log(swaggerUi);
                    }
                    $('pre code').each(function (i, e) {
                        hljs.highlightBlock(e)
                    });
                },
                onFailure: function (data) {
                    if (console) {
                        console.log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI");
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                },
                docExpansion: "none"
            });

            window.swaggerUi.load();
        }
    });
</script>
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set the basePath:

```
package com.example.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.knappsack.swagger4springweb.controller.ApiDocumentationController;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ApiController extends ApiDocumentationController{

        public ApiController() {
        setBasePath("https://force-com-rest-swagger.herokuapp.com");
        setBaseControllerPackage("com.example.controller.api");
        setBaseModelPackage("com.example.model");
        setApiVersion("v1");
    }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public String documentation() {
                return "api";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to enable [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) in your server - perhaps your localhost had it enabled, but it isn't enabled in Heroku (I don't really know anything about Heroku).

You need your server to return the following headers:

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS , PUT

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Often, this is done by adding a filter which adds this to all Swagger requests (requests that originate from your Swagger UI)

You can find an example of this in the <s>[Swagger sources.](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/blob/master/samples/java-jaxrs/src/main/java/com/wordnik/swagger/sample/util/ApiOriginFilter.java)</s>

**UPDATE:** My link to the exact place in the Swagger sources is dead; here is a link to [their current repository.](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui)

Comment: Dead link for swagger sources above.

Comment: Yup. I don't know where it's located in the Swagger sources today, but I'll update the answer with a link to the relevant repository.

Comment: What part of the github link is pertinent to the CORS support? It is easy enough to get to swagger api.

Comment: I have not worked with Swagger for years, so I don't know what class replaces the one I originally posted.